# ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'

Tags: solidity, brownie

```
Brownie v1.15.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 43, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "brownie/network/web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File "brownie/network/web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

Comment: Can you please add what your `.env` file looks like (WITHOUT having any actual keys), and your `brownie-config.yaml` as well as the script you ran?

Comment: this is my broniw-config.yaml, is the same as your code on the NFT/ERC-721/Collectible END-TO-END TUTORIAL | Deploy, List on Opensea, Host Metadata on IPFS
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
autofetch_sources: 
dotenv: .env

  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and what worked for me was adding `dotenv: .env` on the `brownie-config.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this line to .env file:

> export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID='3fcea.....'

Type in your terminal the following line:

> echo $WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID

It worked for me :-)